# US citizen husband visiting me in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, spain

My husband (US citizen) is coming over from November 4th until Jan 21st 2015.
Can we take a cruise holiday in Spain and then return to the UK for the remainder of his visit?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/non-eu-spouse-of-an-eu-citizen-is-visiting-eu-without-needing-a-visa-possible

Comment: What passports do YOU hold??

Answer (score 2):

US Citizens entering on a US passport don't generally require a visa for the Schengen area or the UK. In the UK, if they have been previously denied a visa, it is recommended to apply for one.

Also the UK is not part of the Schengen area and Spain is. So the US citizen can enter Spain visa-free for 3 months and the UK visa-free for 6 months.

My wife is a US citizen and she has entered both those countries without a visa before.

Comment: Thank you for your time..so its ok for him to land in the uk..stay with me for a while then us go on the cruise and both return to the uk so he can continue his time with me until the 90 day period is up and he returns to the US.  I am aware that his visit with me and the cruise all count towards the 90 day stay. So many websites are not clear with their answers .

Comment: The UK is separate from the Schengen zone. You get a separate stamp for each.

Comment: @tracy time spent in the UK does not count toward the 90/180 Schengen calculation, because the UK is not part of the Schengen area.  The websites must have been very unclear indeed.  Also, if you are an EU, non-UK citizen (because that's where you live), your husband can essentially spend as much time as he likes in any EU country as long as he is there with you.

Answer (score 2):

I am a dual US-UK citizen.  Before getting my UK citizenship, I have travelled to Europe extensively and visited UK a number of times - always without a visa.  Same goes for Schengen countries, including Spain.

If you need official citation though, here is the link to the [UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism) that confirms that US citizens do not require a visa for holiday/family visit to the UK. Note that without a visa, the US citizen can stay in the UK for up to 6 months (actually, 180 days).

Similarly, here's the link to the [Spain government website](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/CheckPassport.aspx) confirming that citizens of USA do not require a visa to enter Spain on holiday for up to 90 days.