# Schengen visa for Indonesian citizen traveling to Estonia to get married

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

So I (Estonian citizen) and my girlfriend (Indonesian) are living in Indonesia and planning to get married. We would like to get married in Estonia and then return to Indonesia.

As I would imagine the biggest issue with this kind of application will be to prove that she will return to her country. What if she has weak ties to her country (on paper), job in small company, no property to her name, comes from poor family etc. I will of course make the invitation and sponsor her trip.

What is the proper procedure to apply for a Schengen visa for such purpose?

Comment: Once you are married, the two of you have the right and work in every EU country with the potential exception of Estonia. So ties to Indonesia shouldn't be that important. I would expect that they'll rather care whether you have a genuine relationship, rather than eg she romance-scamming you or you sex-trafficking her.

Comment: So I assume they expect proof of long lasting relationship? We could provide that considering we have been together for 6 years.

Comment: It's probably faster to ring the nearest Estonian embassy than rely on stack exchange in this instance. EU states generally recognise long-term partnerships as equivalent to marriage, and your embassy should be able to advise you on this. Assuming that you can show that you've been together for sufficiently long in the way that's acceptable to your country.

Answer (score -1):

**It will be much easier to get legally married first in Indonesia and only then go to Estonia.**  Once they are a "core family member" of a Schengen citizen, they basically have the right to join you in the EU and visa processing is much more straightforward:

https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

Comment: Free movement does not generally apply to non-EU family members when they are traveling with the EU citizen to country of nationality, as is the case here.  The second paragraph of the linked page: "However, this does not apply to the country of your nationality. If, for example, you are a German national and your non-EU family members want to join you in Germany national rules apply."

Comment: @phoog That's for *residing* in the country of nationality. This is discussed in detail in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/non-eu-spouse-of-an-eu-citizen-is-visiting-eu-without-needing-a-visa-possible, and while I see you've left dissenting comments there as well, I don't see an answer from you explaining why?